# Где в коде jQuery ошибка?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не могу найти ошибку, подумал тут помогут.
Суть такова: в тег `h2` должен с помощью `jQuery` поместится знак `!`.
Вот сам код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Урок 20</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("h2").html("!");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2 id="h2" style="display:block"></h2>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Скорее всего элемента h2 еще нет, когда выполняется jquery код.

Comment: Нет разобрался. Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Где весь код? Тут телепатов нет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорее всего элемента h2 еще нет (ведь код выполняется сверху вниз) когда выполняется jquery код.

Решения 2:

1. Разместить код внизу страницы
2. Обернуть код в callback функцию

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("h2").html("!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2></h2>
```

Подробнее читать [тут](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Answer (score 2):

Вижу несколько вариантов:

1. Ваш код не обернут в тэг script
2. А если обернут, то вызывается перед тегом h2
3. До вызова Вашего кода произошло исключение

Comment: Да код вызывался перед тегом. Спасибо!

Comment: @OlexandrPylypyshyn, а я что написал?

Comment: После вашого коменнтария я и разобрался в проблеме. Я очень вам к благодарен

Comment: @OlexandrPylypyshyn, можете отметить правильный ответ правильным.

Comment: Нужно ждать 3 минуты ещё